# python sqlite3 selecting variables

Tags: python, variables, sqlite

I'm trying to select 3 variables in a sqlite3 statement. And putting this into 3 python variables, can't get it to work..

```
knifekingdb.execute("SELECT rank, rounds, date FROM  knifekingdb WHERE steamid = ?", steamid)
```

I can put it into one list by assigning that statement to a python variabel. But i don't know how to split a list of integers and strings into different variabels.

Can you please help me, because i'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 2):

```
knifekingdb.execute(
    """SELECT rank, rounds, date 
       FROM  knifekingdb WHERE steamid = ? LIMIT 1""", steamid)
try:
    rank, rounds, date = knifekingdb.fetchone()
except TypeError:
    # fetchone returned None because no row was found
    # handle error here
    raise
```

Comment: Have to ask, why use 3 double qoutes?

Comment: @user1868569: you use triple quotes for multiline [strings](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Comment: @user1868569: I find code is more readable when lines are [no longer than ~80 characters](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length). So used a multiline string for the SQL.